# Iterate listview cell values

Tags: asp.net, listview

I'm new in asp.net and trying to pull values from Sqlserver into a listView (asp.net). In codebehind, I want to iterate through all rows and pull cell values for columnX if a checkbox in rowY is checked. I'm getting a compilation error on the following code but cannot figure out the problem. I can get cell values from GridView but not ListView.

```
while (i < WOListView.Items.Count) {
  CheckBox cbCell = (CheckBox)WOListView.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
  if (cbCell.Checked) {
      if (WOListView.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "WO") {
        do stuff...
      }
  }
}
```

And the resulting error code:

> CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem' does not contain a definition for 'SubItems' and no extension method 'SubItems' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem' could be found

Is there a different way of doing this? Is SubItems not supported?

Comment: what are looking for through `.SubItems[1].Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no subitems in listview. If I am not wrong, you are looking for a control inside listview

```
while (i < WOListView.Items.Count) {
  CheckBox cbCell = (CheckBox)WOListView.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
  if (cbCell.Checked) {
      Label somelabel = (Label)WOListView.Items[i].FindControl(“someLabel”);
      //if (WOListView.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "WO") {
       if (somelabel.Text == "WO") {
        do stuff...
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it working for my labels and hidden field. For some reason, I can't get it to work with TextBox. `TextBox gqL = (TextBox)WOListView.Items[i].FindControl("GOOD_QTY")` I'm getting and object reference error when attempting to use `string gq = gqL.Text;` Why would this happen for just the textboxes?

Comment: Scratch that question, I got it working... I was calling an incorrect variable name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is SubItems not supported??

No, which is why you get the compilation error.

It seems to me that you *may* be looking for something like this:

```
while (i < WOListView.Items.Count) {
  CheckBox cbCell = (CheckBox)WOListView.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
  if (cbCell.Checked) {
      if ((WOListView.Items[i].Controls[1] as Label).Text == "WO") {
        do stuff...
      }
  }
}
```

Note the `as Label`. That's assuming you are attempting to check whether a Label control in your ListView row has the text "WO". It may very well be a different kind of control.